# Using React, Flutter for Android instant apps and Apple App Clips

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, flutter

Are there any limitations for using React and/or Flutter for both Android Instant App and Apple App Clips?

I could not find any info, except for size limitation (15/10 MB respectively).

Also, if it is possible, can I use a single code base?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter APK size is too big to support Android Instant Apps. App Clips are experimental (more in [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios-app-clip)).

Comment: Thanks. I figured Flutter would be too big J.

Comment:  Android IA limits the size of 15MB, while iOS AC is 10MB.